# XML generation(JAXB) from JPA with database view

Tags: jpa, jaxb

I have to generate XML using JPA-jaxb . It is done with normal tables mapping, but now I have a database view (11 table relations) for JPA generation.How can I create Entities class for all the tables in the view with relation? . Is that possible?

Comment: The IDEs are supporting this case. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Eclipse I would recommend to use JBoss Tools.

JBoss Tools provide Hibernate reverse engineering:

https://tools.jboss.org/features/hibernate.html